# To use direct page URL or complete path?

Tags: automated-testing, page-objects, selenium3

My question is which approach is recommended when writing automation test for testing something like filters present on page no.3?

1. Should I directly use url of page no.3 in my test file and test filters on the same page.
   Or
2. Use complete path like open home page , click some button to navigate to page no.2 and then navigating to page no.3 by clicking any link.

Should I mimic real user experience like whole path or jus url because I already have test scripts written for page no.1 and 2 ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you talked to your team about which approach would best serve what they need?

Comment: Developers are suggesting to use direct url's because currently my tests are testing more than it should be but I m not sure. What if page 2 navigation is broken.

Comment: Can you get to page 3 without having to go to page 1 and 2?  Is there anything on the first two pages that changes the functionality/layout of page 3?

Comment: Direct url is the only way. It's a ticketing site with events listed like ticketmaster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your post and comments, I think it would be fine for you to just use the direct URL to the page you are testing.  I do similar things in certain tests in my own automation solution.

Having said that, I think you should also create a test that DOES go from page 1 to page 2 and on to page 3. Simply to cover the case you stated of the user experience.

Comment: Ya I can try using suggested approach that way I wll cover both cases. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Like a lot of things in life, it depends.

Both options you lay out will work for test automation. However, what is your overall goal?

Are you testing a feature that is on one page? If so, you can load that page directly and test that feature. This is what you listed as option 1.

Are you testing a feature integration point, like a page redirect? Are you testing an end-to-end user scenario? For these, you'll want start at a beginning point and test from there. This is what you listed as option 2.

Ultimately, you'll probably end up with a mix of these solutions. Some questions to consider are:

- How much setup do you have to do before the filter is applicable?
- What is the intent of the filter while considering end-to-end scenarios?
- How fast do you want your tests to perform?

For example, if you're testing a travel site and want to book a plane ticket for a specific airline, then option 2 is the better option, since you have to setup a departure date/time, starting airport, ending airport, etc. Once the applicable results are loaded, then you can filter per airline.

If you're testing an ecommerce site and you want to filter a category by a sub-category, option 1 would be better, since you most likely will know the direct url for the main category page without having to use a search query or menu navigation to get there.

It really depends on your context and what your test is attempting to assert.

Comment: Very well explained..Thanks for replying @Lee Jensen